# Actualizar Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: oracle, virtualbox, log

He intentado instalar, desinstalar y actualizar Oracle VirtualBox en numerosas ocasiones en Windows 11 (me ocurría el mismo problema en Windows 10) y siempre me ocurre lo siguiente:

[image: Primera Imagen]

[image: Segunda Imagen]

[image: Tercera Imagen]

[image: Cuarta Imagen]

En parte del **archivo log** me aparece esto:

```
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:587]: Executing op: RegRemoveKey()
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:588]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\D282979834F101848B91AAB1602F0C58\Transforms 3: 2 
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:588]: Executing op: End(Checksum=0,ProgressTotalHDWord=0,ProgressTotalLDWord=0)
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:589]: Error in rollback skipped.  Return: 5
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:591]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:592]: Calling SRSetRestorePoint API. dwRestorePtType: 13, dwEventType: 103, llSequenceNumber: 4, szDescription: "".
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:594]: The call to SRSetRestorePoint API succeeded. Returned status: 0.
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:594]: Unlocking Server
    MSI (s) (68:0C) [17:17:05:596]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.
    Action ended 17:17:05: INSTALL. Return value 3.
    CustomAction  returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
    Action ended 17:17:05: RemoveExistingProducts. Return value 3.
    Action ended 17:17:05: INSTALL. Return value 3.
    MSI (s) (68:90) [17:17:05:609]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:612]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:615]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:618]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:619]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:619]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:620]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:622]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:623]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:624]: Destroying RemoteAPI object.
    MSI (s) (68:30) [17:17:05:625]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:05:626]: Back from server. Return value: 1603
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:05:627]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:05:628]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its current value is '1'.
    Action ended 17:17:05: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:05:629]: Doing action: VBoxFatalErrorDlg
    Action start 17:17:05: VBoxFatalErrorDlg.
    DEBUG: Error 2888:  Executing the TextStyle view failed
    The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2888. The arguments are: TextStyle, , 
    DEBUG: Error 2888:  Executing the TextStyle view failed
    The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2888. The arguments are: TextStyle, , 
    Action ended 17:17:14: VBoxFatalErrorDlg. Return value 2.
    Action ended 17:17:14: INSTALL. Return value 3.
    === Logging stopped: 14/10/2021  17:17:14 ===
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:14:978]: Note: 1: 1708 
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:14:979]: Product: Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1.26 -- Installation failed.
    
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:14:980]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1.26. Product Version: 6.1.26. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.
    
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:14:982]: Grabbed execution mutex.
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:14:982]: Cleaning up uninstalled install packages, if any exist
    MSI (c) (CC:20) [17:17:14:984]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
    === Verbose logging stopped: 14/10/2021  17:17:14 ===
```

He tratado de desinstalarlo y/o actualizarlo de diversas formas y ninguna ha funcionado.

Sería de gran ayuda que alguien pudiera explicarme como solucionarlo.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Sobre qué OS instalas? Esa instalación suele [generar un log](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/MSI_Logging), búscalo.

Comment: Instalo sobre Windows 11, pero me ocurría exactamente igual con Windows 10. ¿Como puedo pasarte el .txt? Aquí no me deja subirte ningún archivo.

Comment: Ha intentado arrancar el programa como administrator?

Comment: @Duston Sí. Ocurre lo mismo.

Comment: Pon el txt EN la pregunta, puedes editarla usando el enlace Editar que está justo debajo de la pregunta y las etiquetas

Comment: @Alfabravo Ya he añadido una imagen y texto plano de parte del log. Es extensísimo y no me deja subir el archivo .txt. Solo puedo poner capturas o copiar el texto plano....Espero que con esto sea suficiente.

Comment: Copia el texto.. no uses imagenes salvo que sea ultra necesario.. como se puede copiar de una imagen?

Comment: @gbianchi De acuerdo. Pero es mucho texto....

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo ya la actualización e instalación de las mismas, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).

Comment: En ese caso, ¿qué me recomiendas que haga para solucionarlo? @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent

Comment: intenta la pregunta en serverfault

Comment: pero pareciera un error del isntalador... yo desintalaria todo, ejecutaria ccleaner reinicio y luego validarias que no existanninguna carpeta o archivo o servicio relacionado haria una instalacion limpia del software, prefiero usar vmware 15... pero es de pago..

Comment: Ahí es el problema. Necesito utilizar Oracle VirtualBox y no me deja desinstalarlo porque me aparece el mismo error... @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent

Comment: entonces haslo con cleaner

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130549/discussion-between-arcanis-the-omnipotent-and-nikitamahe97).

Comment: Ni Ccleaner, ni desinstalación normal....NADA me funciona...